# Exception in thread "Thread - " java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, actionlistener

I am currently having some trouble on display errors. When an error occurs, it is called from a method in another class.

```
public void foomethod(Foo foo, Fuu fuu) {
    if(foo.getMethod() == 0) { 
        if(engine.placeMethod(foo, fuu) == true) {
            foo_view.removeCurrentError();
            engine.rollFoo(foo, frame.getInitialDelay(), frame.getFinalDelay(), frame.getDelayIncrement());
        }
        else {
            foo.placeMethod(0);
        }
    }
    else { 
        foo_view.displayCurrentError("Foo has already placed a method"); 
    }   
}
```

And this is the thread

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int fuu = Integer.parseInt(frame.getGameView().getFooView().getMethod());
                Foo bet_foo = frame.getGameView().getFooView().getFoo();
                foomethod(bet_foo, fuu);
            } catch (NumberFormatException excpetion) {
                System.err.println("fuu is not an integer");
            }           
        }
    }.start();  
}
```

The error it displays is

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
at controller.FooListener.rollFooDice(FooListener.java:31) <-- this is foo_view.removeCurrentError();
at controller.FooListener$1.run(FooListener.java:57) <-- this is .start();
```

The problem is when I call `foo_view.removeCurrentError();` the error shows up and the error display shows the same exception.

Comment: Those don't help the OP solve their issue.

Comment: @OP Please display the `controller.FooListener.rollFooDice(` method for us please.

Comment: @Rohlex32 Forgot to edit that, rollFooDice is foomethod()

Comment: @Lutzi  may i ask why this question is a possible duplicate?

Comment: what OP is stands for?

Comment: Where are you setting `foo_view`?

Comment: @oreh It’s Original Poster, i.e. the person who asked the question

Comment: @Rohlex32, Helping the OP solve their problem should be a secondary concern here. We want the OP to _understand_ the problem. Answers on the "What is a NullPointerException..." question provide ideas for how to debug an  NPE (i.e., how to find out which pointer is null and why).

Comment: @Jay Lee, he just answers exactly what I would answer. If this question arise "Why do I have a null pointer exception", it means you didn't understand this exception and how to fix it. We can't answer all NPE, posters have to search a bit for their errors and to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`foo.getMethod()` <- this method

`foo_view.removeCurrentError();` <- This line 
....^ This variable is still null at the point when this line of code is being exectued.